# Operator Priority in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I just spent a frustrating few hours trying to debug code some, through a process of elimination I was able to fix the problem but I can't figure out the cause and its bugging me just as much.

So a bit of context: we want to filter an array of objects (which we will just refer to as type `Object`) based on a collection of predicates of type `Object -> Bool`. We first combine all the predicates into a composed function and then use the filter function with our composed predicate to get the filtered array of objects. So heres an example:

```
var predicateA: (Object -> Bool) = { (obj) in obj.isFoo }
var predicateB: (Object -> Bool) = { (obj) in obj.isBar }
var composedPredicate: (Object -> Bool) {
  return { (obj) in
    return predicateA(obj) && predicateB(obj)
  }
}
```

The above example works perfectly but when try to introduce an optional for the predicates, it doesn't work as expected.

```
var predicateA: (Object -> Bool) = { (obj) in obj.isFoo }
var optionalPredicateB: (Object -> Bool)? = nil
var composedPredicate: (Object -> Bool) {
  return { (obj) in
    return predicateA(obj) 
      && optionalPredicateB != nil ? optionalPredicateB!(obj) : true
  }
}
```

So the code above will cause the composedPredicate to always return true even if the one of the "sub-predicates" return false.

This can be fixed by changing the optionPredicateLine to include parans

```
&& (optionalPredicateB != nil ? optionalPredicateB!(obj) : true)
```

**EDIT:**

I believe the error is due to the priority on the operators in the ternary operator i.e. it is evaluating all the `&&` statements before the `?` in the ternary operator when determining which case to use.

Although I'm not 100% sure on this so i am looking for clarification / or if the cause is something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the precedence of the operators [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/operator_declarations). It shows "&&" has a precedence of 120, whereas "?:" has a precedence of 100, and "!=" is 130. Therefore the "&&" is being evaluated before the ternary operator, which is the equivalent of:

```
return (predicateA(obj) && (optionalPredicateB != nil)) ? optionalPredicateB!(obj) : true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Swift list of infix operators [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/operator_declarations). They are ordered by decreasing order of precedence.

Answer (score -1):

In this line

```
return predicateA(obj) 
      && optionalPredicateB != nil ? optionalPredicateB!(obj) : true
```

Compiler is taking

```
predicateA(obj) 
      && optionalPredicateB != nil
```

as a condition for ternary that's why it was not working so now you added braces so it is working fine